# Xcode 12.4 - How to duplicate a line using a shortcut

Tags: xcode

I am trying to figure out how to use a shortcut to duplicate a line of code in Xcode version 12.4 (Especially in the .swift files, the current duplicate "cmd + D" shortcut works only for UIBuilder).

I saw a lot of documentation on the internet but nothing referring to newest versions of Xcode.
Has anybody tried to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works for me:
open `IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist` in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/`
Add new -> Dictionary -> Add new Item inside -> new Item set String `selectLine:, copy:, moveToEndOfLine:, insertNewline:, paste:, deleteBackward:`
Like this:[image]

Then assign a key in Xcode -> Preferences -> Key Bindings
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your question was specifically for Xcode 12.4, but in Xcode 14.3 (14E222b) a simple `Cmd + D` works fine for duplicating lines.